# Face-api.js for detecting face expression not working on IOS

Tags: javascript, angular, face-api

I am using face-api.js for detecting face expression.On IOS devices(Ipad, Iphone) camera is not getting opened but in android it is working fine.

Code That i am using

Can anyone help me why it is not getting opened on IOS please.

`

```
async ngOnInit() {
    await Promise.all([faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('../../../assets/models'),
    await faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('../../../assets/models'),
    await faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('../../../assets/models'),
    await faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('../../../assets/models'),]).then(() => this.startVideo());
    }

    startVideo() {
      
      this.videoInput = this.video.nativeElement;
      navigator.getUserMedia(
        { video: {}, audio: false },
        (stream:any) =>{ this.videoInput.srcObject = stream},
        (err:any) =>{ console.log(err)}
      );
      this.detect_Faces();
      }

      async detect_Faces() {
        this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('video').addEventListener('play', async () => {
      this.show_tip = true;
         this.canvas = await faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(this.videoInput);
         this.canvasEl = this.canvasRef.nativeElement;
         this.canvasEl.appendChild(this.canvas);
         this.canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvass');
         this.canvas.setAttribute(
            'style',`position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            autoplay: true;
            controls: true;
            playsinline: true;
            loop: true;`
         );
         this.displaySize = {
            width: this.videoInput.width,
            height: this.videoInput.height,
         };
         faceapi.matchDimensions(this.canvas, this.displaySize);
        //  setInterval(async () => {
           this.detection = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(this.videoInput,  new  faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions();
           this.resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(
              this.detection,
              this.displaySize
            );
           this.canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0,      this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);
        
          if (this.resizedDetections.length > 0 ) {
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.width = 1600;
                canvas.height = 1200;
                canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this.video.nativeElement, 0, 0);
            
                const img = document.createElement("img");
                // const dataUrl = 
                // img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                //  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(p);
                img.src = canvas.toDataURL().replace("image/base64", "image/webp");
            
                // document.getElementById('screenshot').appendChild(img)
                console.log(img.src);
                this.faceSearch(img.src);
                
                        }
        });
        }
```

```
`
```

the same code is working on Android but not on IOS

Comment: Sorry My Bad. Edited Now

Comment: check all the DOM API's you're using (i.e. the standard browser ones) to make sure they are supported in Safari - hint: specifically check `navigator.getUserMedia` - it's deprecated and never supported in Safari

Comment: ok @JaromandaX. i was testing it on chrome browser on IPAD. Still camera not getting opened

Comment: so, did you discover the issue regarding `navigator.getUserMedia`?

Comment: Could not find anything. Because in browser it is working fine and in android devices as well

Comment: I always find **MDN** a good source of *documentation* ... for instance - [Navigator.getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) note the deprecation notice and the browser support does NOT include Safari -

Comment: And, there's also another important note. Any browser on iOS, no matter its name, still uses Safari (WebKit).

Comment: Hi @manish_jsohi_1996 Did you manage to find a solution for this one? I'm facing the same issues too

Comment: Hi @JoãoMartins were you able to solve the issue? I am facing the same issue now. Help!!!